# textinput value on scrollview

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-textinput

i want to change value of textInput but it change all value of textinput , i know because of the state, but what the right way to handle this textInput or what i use is numericInput from react-native-numeric-input,  thanks for helping.

```
<ScrollView>
  {this.state.display.map((info)=>{
    return 
    <View style={{paddingBottom:5,alignSelf:'center'}} key={info.id}>
      <View style={{ ... }}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          ...
          <View style={{justifyContent:'center',marginLeft:'auto',marginRight:10}}>
            <NumericInput 
              totalWidth={70} 
              totalHeight={30} 
              iconSize={10}
              initValue={this.state.v6}
              value={this.state.v6}
              onChange={(v6) => this.setState({ v6 })} 
              rounded 
              textColor='#59656F' 
              iconStyle={{ color: 'white' }} 
              rightButtonBackgroundColor='#AC9FBB' 
              leftButtonBackgroundColor='#DDBDD5' 
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View> 
  })}
</ScrollView>
```

and this my state code

```
state={
  v6:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the onChange to this:

```
onChange={(value) => this.setState({ v6: value })}
```